# script to associate columns

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting

I have a file consisting of definitions where a variable name points to an ip address. I want a script (bash/python/similar) to output each ip address followed by a list of each variable where it is defined as well as how many variables were in the list.

Input:

```
define alpha    192.168.1.1
define beta     192.168.1.3
define gamma    192.168.1.2
define delta    192.168.1.1
define epsilon  192.168.1.3
define zeta     192.168.1.1
define eta      192.168.1.3
define theta    192.168.1.1
```

Output

```
192.168.1.1:alpha,delta,zeta,theta:4
192.168.1.3:beta,epsilon,eta:3
192.168.1.2:gamma:1
```

Do I use associative arrays in bash to do this or is there a better way? I tried to do it but only ended up with a bash script which I had to combine with linux `sort` and `uniq` commands but still couldn't get it quite right.

Apologies for crappy title but I couldn't formulate this in a better way so feel free to edit.

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have added clear sample of input and sample of expected output in your post, we encourage all users to add their efforts too in their post so kindly do so, happy learning on this GREAT site SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following. This should be able to have those values even you have more than 1 values after keyword `define`(1st field) and between last field(IP address), though your example do not have more than 3 fields but I have taken care of that(in case your Input_file is having more than 3 fields in it too).

```
awk '{$1="";val=$NF;$NF="";gsub(/^ +| +$/,"");a[val]=a[val]?a[val]","$0:$0;b[val]++}  END{for(i in a){print i":"a[i]":"b[i]}}' Input_file
```

OR adding a non-one liner form of solution here.

```
awk '
{
  $1=""
  val=$NF
  $NF=""
  gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")
  a[val]=a[val]?a[val]","$0:$0
  b[val]++
}
END{
  for(i in a){
      print i":"a[i]":"b[i]
  }
}'   Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Above 1st solution will NOT give same order of IPs(which they are present in Input_file), this solution will take care of sequence of IPs in output should be same as Input_file's presence.

```
awk '{$1="";val=$NF;$NF="";gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")} !c[val]++{d[++count]=val} {a[val]=a[val]?a[val]","$0:$0;b[val]++}  END{for(i=1;i<=count;i++){print d[i]":"a[d[i]]":"b[d[i]]}}'  Input_file
```

OR(adding a non-one liner form of above solution).

```
awk '
{
  $1=""
  val=$NF
  $NF=""
  gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")
}
!c[val]++{
  d[++count]=val
}
{
  a[val]=a[val]?a[val]","$0:$0
  b[val]++
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
      print d[i]":"a[d[i]]":"b[d[i]]
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Much appreciate your quick answer (I saw it earlier but didn't reply until now).

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk '
  /^define/{
    a[$3]++
    b[$3]=(b[$3]?b[$3]",":"")$2
  }
  END {
    for(i in a)
      print i,b[i],a[i]
  }' OFS=: file
```

`a` is an array that holds the count of each different IP.
`b` is an array that holds a string containing all keywords for each IP. A comma is inserted in between every keyword.

At the end of the parsing the index containing the IP and both arrays content are printed.

The `OFS=:` sets the output field separator to `:`.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't seem to be quite working for me. I only get the last occurence of each IP. The counter is correct though.

Comment: @hysteryteacher There was a typo with `b[$3]`, answer updated. Please retry.